# MySQL: Add Texts Above Query Results' Headers Before Output Into CSV Format

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am creating a *Stored Procedure* that generates a report with dynamic columns to export as CSV in CodeIgniter.

About at the end of an *SP*:

```
...
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 32000;
SET @sql_pivot = NULL;

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'MAX(CASE WHEN col4 = ''',
          col4,
          ''' THEN col5 END) AS ',
          col4
        )
    ) INTO @sql_pivot
FROM last_tmp_table;

SET @sql_pivot = CONCAT('SELECT col1, col2, ', @sql_pivot, ' FROM last_tmp_table GROUP BY col3');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_pivot;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
...
```

This outputs data with pivot row into dynamic columns:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| header1 | header2 | dynamic_header3 | dynamic_header4 | ... | dynamic_headerN |
| value1 | value2 | dynamic_value3 | dynamic_value4 | ... | dynamic_valueN |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I tried using `UNION`, but it doesn't work because the columns are dynamic.

How can I **add text information before the headers?** For example:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Title: | title_value |  |  |  |  |
| Full name: | fullname_value |  |  |  |  |
| Address: | address_value |  |  |  |  |
| Date and Time: | datetime_value |  |  |  |  |
| header1 | header2 | dynamic_header3 | dynamic_header4 | ... | dynamic_headerN |
| value1 | value2 | dynamic_value3 | dynamic_value4 | ... | dynamic_valueN |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Use a query with needed string literals UNIION ALL your qury - UNION ALL does not reorder the rows.

Comment: Either that, or write them to the file using PHP before you output the rest of the data into it